# Asterisk - How to handle multi-digit inputs

Tags: asterisk

I have an Asterisk server running with a (mostly) working dialplan.

I have this scenario:

At one point the caller hears "Enter any number".
He then enters a number on his phone.

If he enters 0 i want to jump to 'Context0' in the dialplan.
If he enters a number from 1 to 10000 i want to jump to 'Context1'.
If the entered number is higher than 10000 I want to jump to 'Context2'.

The context that handles this scenario looks like this:

```
[Context]
exten => 100,1,Background(/var/lib/asterisk/sounds/sound)

exten => 0,1,Goto(Context0,100,1)
exten => _Z,1,Goto(Context1,100,1)
exten => _ZX,1,Goto(Context1,100,1)
exten => _ZXX,1,Goto(Context1,100,1)
exten => _ZXXX,1,Goto(Context1,100,1)
exten => 10000,1,Goto(Context1,100,1)

exten => i,1,Goto(Context2,100,1)
```

This works if I only enter 5 digits. If i enter f.e. 123456 then after 12345 it enters the 'i extension', goes to Context2 and applies the last digit (in this case number 6) in this context.

So my question is, how can I make the dialplan check if the input is greater than 10000 and if it is greater jump to Context2?

I hope you understand my problem, my English isn't so good.. :)

Many thanks and best regards

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Read](http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+cmd+Read) function and do whatever checks you want:

```
[Context]
exten => 100,1,Read(mynumber,/var/lib/asterisk/sounds/sound,10,skip,1,5)
same => n,GotoIf($[${mynumber} = 0]?Context0,100,1)
same => n,GotoIf($[${mynumber} <= 10000]?Context1,100,1:Context2,100,1)
```

Above code is not tested and may require some tweaks.

Comment: But if I try this with Read, it always hangs up. In the logs I always see this:

[Oct 24 11:34:57] WARNING[1356][C-00000000] pbx.c: No application 'Read' for extension (Context, s, 1)

I also tried something simple like this: [link](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/The+Read+Application) But it gives me the same error...

Do I have to configure something that I can use the application 'Read'?

Comment: @simplex ensure that `app_read.so` is loaded. If your asterisk is not configured to load it automatically, you can load it manually with `module load app_read.so` command and rerun your test.

Answer (score 0):

You may just have to set the inter-digit timeout or press pound (#) when finished. The timeout can be set using:

```
Set(TIMEOUT(digit)=5)
```

Or on older versions (<1.2):

```
DigitTimeout(5)
```

It should be set in before the *Background* cmd in the dialplan.

Answer (score 0):

123456 is invalid because your patterns do not allow for 6 digit numbers. (Your patterns don't allow for 5 digit numbers except for 10000 either.)

I would suggest you re-think what you are doing and why.

Do you really mean 'any number?' What if I try to enter 100,000 digits?

Would it be possible to change "Enter any number" to "Enter up to x digits followed by the pound key?"

You could then use the 'read()' application and a couple of 'gotoif()s' to route the caller to the different contexts.

Maybe if you explained what you are trying to accomplish, a better method could be suggested.